# Why is my background div jumping when I use jQuery animate height?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, height

**UPDATE: Recreated my problem in jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/3v8vW/3/

I have 2 tabs, clicking on short should shorten the height of the form-background, and clicking on tall should increase the height. However there should not be any jarring / 'skippy' animation going on like so.

When you click on a tab, the other tab is hidden.

**Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wipba**

If you **click on login** you will see the animation happen. The login div has a height of 290px and register is 410px.

I got the animate code from this [simple example here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/understanding-jquery-animate-function/).

What I'm trying to do is just animate the height extending down or shrinking up, the position and width should stay the same. I had to set `top` and `width` because otherwise my `.form-background` div would do some crazy resizing and not end at the correct position after the animation.

Do you know what is going on here? And how would you go about hacking it? :)

[image]

*jQuery*

```
    // tabs
    $('#login-form #tab-register').click(function() {

        $('#login-form').fadeToggle();
        $(".form-background").animate(
            {
                "top": "-342px",
                "width": "400px",
                "height": "410px"
            },
            "slow", function(){
                $('#register-form').fadeToggle();
            });
    });

    $('#register-form #tab-login').click(function() {

        $('#register-form').fadeToggle();
        $(".form-background").animate(
            {
                "top": "-214px",
                "width": "400px",
                "height": "290px"
            },
            "slow", function(){
                $('#login-form').fadeToggle();
            });
    });
```

*CSS*

```
.container .login-container .login-box .form-background {
  position: relative;
  top: -342px;
  height: 410px;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/wipba

Comment: i dont see any animation happening, chrome on ubuntu

Comment: Oh strange, I'm on OSX and works on my chrome, FF and safari

Comment: what is the id of login? where jquery function is called? i dont see anim in ff fedora!!

Comment: Using [magic numbers](http://css-tricks.com/magic-numbers-in-css/) could trip you up at some point later when you're cross browser and backwards compatibility testing. These days everybody should be trying to use responsive units of measurement. Also, you could try `animate({"height":"auto"})` - as long as you haven't positioned everything absolutely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3v8vW/16/)**

Put your `tabs` outside. There is no need to repeat it for each your tab content:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='topbar'>
        <ul>
            <li class="short btn-off">Short</li>
            <li class="tall btn-off">Tall</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tall-content">
        <div>
            Tall Content
        </div>  
    </div>

    <div class="short-content">
        <div>
            Short Content
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div id='form-bg'></div>
</div>
```

Also I overwrote your animation algorithm, first hide the other one, with no animation,
then show the current one with fade animation:

```
$(".short").click(function(){
    $('.tall-content').hide();
    $("#form-bg").animate({height:100},200);
    $('.short-content').fadeIn();
});

$(".tall").click(function(){
    $('.short-content').hide();
    $("#form-bg").animate({height:200},200);
    $('.tall-content').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Thanks that totally fixed my problem! I knew it was my markup making things hard

Answer (score 1):

Please check here: http://jsfiddle.net/nucky/Cu59K/

```
.topbar { 
  position: absolute; 
  top:0;
}

#form-bg {
  position:absolute; 
  top:60px;
}
```

Comment: Could not get that to work either, I think the problem is somewhere in my markup, with the absolute positioniong

Comment: I recreated my problem in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/3v8vW/3/ this may showcase the problem better

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` this will stop the jump you are referring too

Comment: which selector do I add that too?

Comment: Hmm tried, that didn't work... maybe I possibly need to add another div element to hide the animation spazzing

Comment: I recreated the problem in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/3v8vW/3/ The problem happens because I have 2 tabs, 1 tab is hidden always. This could possibly be causing my background height problem